# "try" error not working in my kick command

Tags: discord.js

I've made a kick command but it doesn't work correctly. It shows an error when trying to kick an admin, this error is handled tho. Also, when it gives the error, it puts in the chat: "member has been kicked", but it doesn't kick that user.

```
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        var member = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
            try {
                member.kick()
                message.channel.send(" " + member.user.tag + " has been kicked " + "")
            } catch {
                message.reply("I do not have permissions to kick that user")
            } 
            } else {
                message.reply("You do not have permissions to kick users")
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
member.kick()
.then(member=> message.channel.send(" " + member.user.tag + " has been kicked " + ""))
.catch(()=>message.reply("I do not have permissions to kick that user"))
```

We can use the promise from the kick() method to see if the member was successfully kicked or if there has been an error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (message.author.bot) return false;

var member = message.mentions.members.first();
if (!member) return message.reply(`Please mention someone to kick.`);

if (message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
    if (member.kickable) {
        member.kick();
        message.channel.send(` ${member.user.tag} has been kicked. `);
    } else {
        message.reply(`I can't kick ${member.user.tag}.`);
    }
} else {
    message.reply(`You do not have permissions to kick users.`);
};
```